# Mavens stopped working - cannot find project file for: myCurrProject

Tags: apex, mavensmate

My maven's stopped working last night, and now I'm getting the  error that maven's can't find the porject file for my project. Also, I don't see a sublime settings file there either.

I may have junked them by mistake using stash, but can't see a record of them there.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

I copied those files from another project, and it seemed to fix the problem, but i'mnot sure if this is ok...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - Not Salesforce related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to do the same thing in the past but instead of copying from another project, I did the following:

Renamed existing project folder by adding .bak
Created a new project in MavensMate
Closed Sublime and copied missing project and sublime files from new project to old project.bak folder
Deleted new project folder
Removed .bak from end of old project folder
Reopened Sublime
Opened MavensMate Project

Ran across this in the MavensMate [docs](https://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Existing_Projects), you are probably better off treating it as an existing project:

> PROJECT LOCATED ON YOUR LOCAL FILESYSTEM
>
> Drag directory into Sublime Text
>
> 1. Right click the project root in the Sublime Text sidebar
> 2. Select MavensMate > Create MavensMate Project.
> 3. You will then be prompted for Salesforce.com credentials.